# Recieving a 404 error when trying to open posts after permalink change to /%pagename%/

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, permalinks

I’ve changed my custom permalink setting to /%pagename%/ (which is common, I guess). However, the following problem keeps occurring:

When trying to open a post on my website, I receive a 404 error. When changing the permalink setting back to Standard, the errors disappear.

After googling, I found that there is a way to solve this by editing your .htaccess file. Even after this, the same problem reoccurs. As I would like to have clean page-names, would anyone know how to solve this problem?

Greetings,
Tom

Comment: Shouldn't it be `%postname%` instead? I'm not sure `%pagename%` is a valid option.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly delete your .htaccess file from the root folder and check your site again, if the problem is still there than regenerate the permalinks using %postname%.

Comment: I've tried all this. I specifically want the permalink to display my page name, not the post name.

Answer (score 0):

For the url rewriting WP feature to work, WP writes the .htaccess file at the root of your WP installation.

Open the .htaccess file and check whether or not you have this piece of code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

If it is missing, you have 2 options:

- change the file permissions so that WP can write it.
- or add the missing code yourself to the .htaccess.

Comment: maybe you should be more responsive if you want others to help you.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. I'm new on Stack overflow and messed up my notification settings